# Regex for hashtags tree takes too long to execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

In our app we have topics which user can create, and each topic must have it's own hashtag (or hashtags hierarchy). We have this kinda Regex for validation:

```
const REGEX_HASHTAG = /^(#[w]?((\/?)([a-z0-9]+)+)+)(,\s{0,1}#[a-z0-9]?((\/?)([a-z0-9]+)+)+)*$/g;
```

What i need is for user to be able to create hashtags which have structure like this:

1. (#) symbol
2. Text in lowercase
3. Optional slash (/) followed by lowercase text to create hierarchy

And also users can put comma (and optional whitespace) followed by new hashtag or hashtag hierarchy. When i put too many letters and slash at the end Regex stops working, takes too long to execute. What am i doing wrong?

regexr.com/6hpqo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few nested quantifiers and optional parts, which can cause catastrophic backtracking when there is no match.

You could write the pattern as

```
^#[a-z0-9]+(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)*(?:,\s*#[a-z0-9]+(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)*)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `#[a-z0-9]+` Match # and 1+ repetitions of the listed characters in the character class
- `(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat the `/` and the same character class
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,\s*` Match a comma and optional whitespace chars
  - `#[a-z0-9]+(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)*` The same pattern as in the first part
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SYWw2F/1)